# How to get File Stream from a custom FileUpload in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I needed a FileUpload which would look almost same in all browsers i.e show file input field in chrome as well. So i am using a custom FileUpload
With this code..

**CSS**

```
    <style type="text/css">



        #FileUpload {
    position:relative;
            top: -4px;
            left: 0px;
        }

#BrowserVisible {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background:url(upload.gif) 100% 0px no-repeat;
    height:26px;
    width:240px;
}

#FileField {
    width:155px;
    height:22px;
    margin-right:85px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    font-size:16px;
}

#BrowserHidden {
    position:relative;
    width:240px;
    height:26px;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

    </style>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="zoom/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.custom-upload input[type=file]').change(function () {
        $(this).next().find('input').val($(this).val());
    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="FileUpload">
    <input type="file" size="24" id="BrowserHidden" runat="server" onchange="getElementById('FileField').value = getElementById('BrowserHidden').value;" />
    <div id="BrowserVisible"><input type="text" id="FileField" runat="server" /></div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" style="height: 26px" />
</div>
```

With asp.net server control it was as simple as

```
Stream fs = file_upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your markup has something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" />
<br />
<input type="file" id="file2" />
```

In your code-behind event handler, you can get at the file like so:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["file1"]; // Gets contents passed in file1 element
HttpPostedFile file2 = Request.Files["file2"]; // Gets contents passed in file2 element
Stream uploadFileStream = file.InputStream;
// TODO:  Add code to read the streams
```

Comment: is this equivalent to `Stream fs = file_upload.PostedFile.InputStream;`

Comment: Using this approach you'd just use Stream fs = file.InputStream;

Comment: what if i have multiple such custom controls? In asp.net FileUpload i can specify whose file stream i want simple by `Stream fs = file_upload1.PostedFile.InputStream;`

Comment: Request.Files is a collection for all files posted to the server.  This collection allows you to access specific members via an indexer that accepts the id of the file upload input.  In the example you provided, your input element was named "BrowserHidden".  If you had another file upload input named "AnotherFile" then you'd get that file via Request.Files["AnotherFile"]

Comment: FYI, updated the code to demonstrate how you'd read multiple files

Comment: One last question .. what will be the `file_upload.HasFile` equivalent in this case? How can i check if a particular control has file and check its extension. 
I am sorry i am troubling you a lot. +1

Comment: I believe you'd check to see if Request.Files["file1"] != null to ensure the file was actually uploaded

Comment: I did that, i just thought there might be someother way as well anyways...  if you can tell me how i can find the extension , i will really be very grateful to you. i am going to select mark your post an answer anyways you have been great help.

Comment: Sorry, the null check is the only approach I'm aware of when using Request.Files

Comment: Request.Files["file1"].fileName should have the extension.